# how to use update() for random part in lmer()?

Tags: r, lme4

I would like to use the `update()` function to update the random part of my model, specifically, adding a random effect. Most examples (`help("update")`, `help("update.formula")`, [lme4:mixed effects modeling with R](http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/lMMwR/lrgprt.pdf)) focus on the fixed part of the model. How would I go from `fm0` to `fm1` using `update()` in the example below?

```
library(lme4)
(fm0 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), sleepstudy))
(fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 + Days | Subject), sleepstudy))
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I doubt this will be useful in your case, but you have to remove the random effect and then add the desired on back in:

```
update(fm0, . ~ . -(1|Subject) + (1 + Days | Subject))
```

Comment: this is exactly right.  It's too bad there's not a more compact way to do it, but it's hard to see how one would specify "update *within* this specified random effects term" (especially as the internal machinery just passes the update specification to R's built-in `update.formula()` method)